# Singularity exec - echo redirect issue

Tags: echo, singularity-container

I am running a singularity container with ubuntu xenial base.

When I attempt to create a text file by using redirect from echo command to the file system the target of the redirect is interpreted to be on the host instead of on the container.

Below is the command -

```
singualrity exec ubuntu_xenial_image.img echo "test" >> /mnt/test.txt
```

Instead of creating the file test.txt in the container folder named /mnt, it tries to write the test.txt file to the host root folder /mnt/test.txt resulting in a - no permissions error as obviously I don't have permission to write to the host root folder.

Do you know why the redirect goes to the host file system rather than the container file system as the *singularity exec* command is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

The full command, as it is written is divided into

```
singularity exec ubuntu_xenial_image.img echo "test"
```

for the container and the output is redirected to **>> /mnt/test.txt** in the host filesystem.

to correct it

```
$ singularity exec ubuntu_xenial_image.img sh -c "echo" test ">> /mnt/test.txt"
```

thus the complete command will be interpreted by sh inside the container.

In addition to this, you need to verify the write permissions of the **/mnt** directory, or execute with **sudo**.

Comment: Thank you! will give it a try.

Comment: In case the information has been useful, I would appreciate your vote on the answer.

Comment: I cannot vote as I am new to stack overflow. But it worked. Thanks!